# Java Similar file selector as FileZilla

Tags: java, swing, file, filezilla

I am creating a program which needs to show files from the computer. But I can't find any Swing components and such that can't replicate the File Zilla way to show up. There is JTree but is not good.

[image: FileZilla screenshot]

Comment: Working examples may be found [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446).

Comment: @trashgod Good but anything else?